# php mongodb find not working

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp, php-mongodb

**SOLVED**

To view the data, I was doing a var_dump on the cursor and you have to loop through the cursor first to var_dump it.

```
foreach($user_images as $image) {
     var_dump($image)
}
```

Can find out more about this at:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursor.php

**/SOLVED**

I have a collection called 'user_image' in my MongoDB.  I am using PHP 5.3 with mongoDB db v2.0.5, pdfile version 4.5.  I have this setup in my XAMPP. I am simply trying to find all documents in the collection.  When I run the information below, nothing returns back even though I can confirm in the terminal running the db.user_image.find() that it returns results.

```
$m = new Mongo();
$db = $m->selectDB('dev_app');
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'user_image');
$collection->find();
```

If I change the query to simply use findOne by a user_uuid I get a result! Example below:

```
$collection->findOne(array('user_uuid' => 'de977803-f198-416a-8806-acbc1fa3f718'));
```

Here is an example document in the collection user_image:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("500c3f13ab8692ced0d9df6f"),
    "user_uuid" : "de977803-f198-416a-8806-acbc1fa3f718",
    "image_name" : "4a5e286e101429da0a3c3a576ffa4878.jpg",
    "image_url" : "/uploaded_files/files/4a5e286e101429da0a3c3a576ffa4878.jpg",
    "sm_thumb_url" : "/uploaded_files/thumbnails/4a5e286e101429da0a3c3a576ffa4878.jpg",
    "md_thumb_url" : "/uploaded_files/files/4a5e286e101429da0a3c3a576ffa4878.jpg",
    "lg_thumb_url" : "/uploaded_files/files/4a5e286e101429da0a3c3a576ffa4878.jpg",
    "status" : "A",
    "created" : ISODate("2012-07-22T17:57:36.835Z"),
    "modified" : ISODate("2012-07-22T17:57:36.835Z"),
    "created_by_uuid" : "de977803-f198-416a-8806-acbc1fa3f718",
    "modified_by_uuid" : "de977803-f198-416a-8806-acbc1fa3f718"
}
```

What am I missing in the find query?  Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Solved it! Stupid, stupid, stupid, you can't simply do a var_dump($user_images) to view the result...  You have to loop through the result and dump it to actually view the data.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer to the question, so that the question appears answered.

Comment: If you solved this question, please add answer, how you loop through the result.

Answer (score 0):

## Cursor Object is a 'key' here

The `$cursor = $collection->find();` find() method will return a Cursor Object. 
Now you can use toArray() method to get your data.
`$dataArray = $cursor->toArray();` Simple as that. **Or use foreach to get documents one by one**. Ps. FindOne() which returns an array.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-cursor.php